# Mathematica command assistance

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have a plot and the range is 10 to 5000 on x axes, I now need to reproduce the plot,but after 80 on x axes, I need to multiply the x axes data points by 1.5.
What could be the best commands to do that?
[image]

Comment: Post your code and a bit of your data. Right now it's too difficult to begin to play around to give you any useful help.

Comment: Plot[t2, {y, 1, 1000}, {x, 10, 5000}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 10^-26}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x (multiples of 1.5)", "y "}, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Table[{i, 10^i}, {i, -30, -26}], Automatic}}

Comment: I need to reproduce this redline but after 80 on xaxes, I need to multiply the points of red line with 1.5 and get a plot

Comment: Type `Ticks`, hover over it, press the "i" symbol, then select "Details" on how to custom code the ticks in a plot.  It describs the syntax for the tick marks.